# Could not select a link inside a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code to update all the table cells in a specific row:

```
$('#riga'+id_cella).children('td').each(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass("ore")) {
        $(this).fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $(this).removeClass('planned').addClass('planning');
            $(this).next("a").text('Scegli');
            $(this).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    }
});
```

This code change some css in each cell and should update the text of the href inside the cell to display "Scegli" instead of "solo video". 
The table cell has this code:

```
<td class="planned">
<a id="14" class="plan toPlan" href="plan.php?when=4&who=1" title="Pianifica le ore 03:00 per il gruppo 1 ">solo video</a>
</td>
```

The point is that next(a) seems not to select the href inside the cell. If I write:

```
$(this).text('Scegli');
```

it changes (as expected) the cell content removing the href completely. 
Cannot see what I am doing wrong

Comment: `<a />` is a child not a sibling - [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) ;)

Comment: Right! I have to move one level down on the DOM. Next stays on the same level.

Comment: Then why don't you use `.children()` as you do in `$('#riga'+id_cella).children('td')`?

Comment: This is what I have done now that I've realized my mistake thanks to @Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$(this).next("a").text('Scegli');
```

to this:

```
$(this).find("a").text('Scegli');
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrhvqxob/)

Or better, take advantage of chaining:

```
$('#riga'+id_cella).children('td').each(function(index, element){

    var $ele = $(element),
        noOre = !$ele.hasClass('ore');

    if(noOre){
        $ele.fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $ele.removeClass('planned').addClass('planning').find("a").text('Scegli').end().fadeIn('fast');
        });
    }
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrhvqxob/1/) for that

Comment: $(this).find("a").text('Scegli'); did the trick as well... thanks anyway!